# How to make scroll bar not be covered

Tags: css

I have a base panel called BasePanel whose code cannot be changed.
I have a bar which is always a fixed height and this bar is NOT added in the BasePanel, but it is overlapped with the BasePanel .
I also have a panel called Container which is added to the BasePanel. Panel Container should be just under the Bar.

Now I want when the window size is changed, the Panel Container can automatically appear scroll bar, which I have already implemented but has a problem. The problem is when I window gets small the part of the scroll bar will be covered. I would like to know how I can solve this problem?

```
BasePanel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'Arimo';
}


Bar{
    height: 41px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9998;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}


.Container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95.570321151%;
    top: 4.429678848%;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

If I set container's top as percentage, the up arrow of the scroll bar will be covered by the Bar.

```
.Container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95.570321151%;
    top: 41px;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

If I set container's top as 41px, the down arrow of the scroll bar will be covered because there is no enough space for it.

In other words, I would like to know how I can make the Panel Container always start from top 41px and no matter how the window size is changed, the Container won't get overflowed from the BasePanel so that the scroll bar will not be covered(Remember the Bar is not in the BasePanel)?

[image]

Comment: take a look at the `@media` css queries to do styling based on window size http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I check media query, but I am not sure how they can apply to my case. It provides when the size is some value or between some values, something will happen. My problem is when the window size is getting small, the Panel Container will get overflow and part of the scroll bar will be covered. Could you tell me how to use media qurey to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do it.
Just use calc() function to set the Container Panel height.

Such as calc(100% - 41px)

:)